# Laravel Registering seeds in a package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a package which creates several migrations, which I would like to seed. Then there are some other subpackages, which could also create migrations with seeds. So there can be a lot of seeds around, and I don't want to force users to add tens of lines to DatabaseSeeder.

Something like `php artisan db:seed --class="MyNamespace\\DatabaseSeeder"` would work, but this way users can't migrate and seed with the same command, as `php artisan migrate --seed` doesn't accept the class option.

Basically, I am looking for something similar to `loadMigrationsFrom()` of the `ServiceProvider` class.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm primarily interested in a solution for Laravel 5.3, I'll somehow figure out backward compatibility

Comment: Make a command for your package that does the seeding... `php artisan package_name:seed`

Comment: @Kyslik I thought about that, but that still wouldn't allow users to migrate and seed at the same time. Of course, I could do the migrations for the package through the command as well, but they still would have to migrate their own stuff separately. I would like to be able to use `php artisan migrate --seed`

Comment: Write a good readme and thats it, do not overthink. KISS (keep it simple stupid)

Comment: @Kyslik, yes, probably the way to go, but a solution like `loadMigrationsFrom()` would be nice

Comment: You can instruct your users to use db:seed command;

Comment: in my case when module in subfolders and want to run in directly without running other seeder php artisan db:seed --class=WM\Common\Seeder\SmsStatusSeeder

Answer (score 6):

This work for "db:seed" command and "--seed" option also.

Read more at: https://github.com/wowcee/laravel-seeds-service-provider

```
<?php

namespace Core\Providers;

use Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandFinished;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class SeedServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $seeds_path = '/../database/seeds';


    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            if ($this->isConsoleCommandContains([ 'db:seed', '--seed' ], [ '--class', 'help', '-h' ])) {
                $this->addSeedsAfterConsoleCommandFinished();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a value that indicates whether the current command in console
     * contains a string in the specified $fields.
     *
     * @param string|array $contain_options
     * @param string|array $exclude_options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isConsoleCommandContains($contain_options, $exclude_options = null) : bool
    {
        $args = Request::server('argv', null);
        if (is_array($args)) {
            $command = implode(' ', $args);
            if (str_contains($command, $contain_options) && ($exclude_options == null || !str_contains($command, $exclude_options))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Add seeds from the $seed_path after the current command in console finished.
     */
    protected function addSeedsAfterConsoleCommandFinished()
    {
        Event::listen(CommandFinished::class, function(CommandFinished $event) {
            // Accept command in console only,
            // exclude all commands from Artisan::call() method.
            if ($event->output instanceof ConsoleOutput) {
                $this->addSeedsFrom(__DIR__ . $this->seeds_path);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register seeds.
     *
     * @param string  $seeds_path
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addSeedsFrom($seeds_path)
    {
        $file_names = glob( $seeds_path . '/*.php');
        foreach ($file_names as $filename)
        {
            $classes = $this->getClassesFromFile($filename);
            foreach ($classes as $class) {
                Artisan::call('db:seed', [ '--class' => $class, '--force' => '' ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get full class names declared in the specified file.
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return array an array of class names.
     */
    private function getClassesFromFile(string $filename) : array
    {
        // Get namespace of class (if vary)
        $namespace = "";
        $lines = file($filename);
        $namespaceLines = preg_grep('/^namespace /', $lines);
        if (is_array($namespaceLines)) {
            $namespaceLine = array_shift($namespaceLines);
            $match = array();
            preg_match('/^namespace (.*);$/', $namespaceLine, $match);
            $namespace = array_pop($match);
        }

        // Get name of all class has in the file.
        $classes = array();
        $php_code = file_get_contents($filename);
        $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
        $count = count($tokens);
        for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
                $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
                if ($namespace !== "") {
                    $classes[] = $namespace . "\\$class_name";
                } else {
                    $classes[] = $class_name;
                }
            }
        }

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't find a native function which loads in the right order, includes the files and executes them. Method is crude, but works. The migrate:refresh --seed won't work with this method, as it assumes tables exist when the service provider is run, however db:seed does.

```
                protected function registerSeedsFrom($path)
                {
                    foreach (glob("$path/*.php") as $filename)
                    {
                        include $filename;
                        $classes = get_declared_classes();
                        $class = end($classes);

                        $command = Request::server('argv', null);
                        if (is_array($command)) {
                            $command = implode(' ', $command);
                            if ($command == "artisan db:seed") {
                                Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => $class]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Works with a custom service provider/package in the boot method:

```
    if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->registerMigrations();
        $this->registerEloquentFactoriesFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/factories');
        $this->registerSeedsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/seeds');
```

}

Comment: Do you have the full file somewhere? I like your solution and would love to see how you included the factories as well with ->registerEloquentFactoriesFrom. thanks!

Comment: What are the namespaces of `Artisan` and `Request` classes?

Answer (score 1):

```
 php artisan db:seed --class="Package\Name\database\seeds\NameTableSeeder"
```

Comment: A code-only answer is not high quality.  Please edit it to add explanation.  What does this command do?  How do you know it is needed?  How does it answer the question?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to explain how this answers the question?  The question specifically mentions that `php artisan db:seed` does not fully meet their needs: *Something like `php artisan db:seed --class="MyNamespace\\DatabaseSeeder"` would work, but this way users can't migrate and seed with the same command, as `php artisan migrate --seed` doesn't accept the class option.*

Answer (score 0):

File 'app/Demo/Database/Migrations/Table_DemoTypes.php':

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('demo_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->integer('f_integer');
        });

        if (\App::runningInConsole()) {
            $args = Request::server('argv', null);
            if (is_array($args) && array_intersect($args, ['db:seed', '--seed'])) {
                Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'App\\Demo\\Database\\Seeders\\Seeder_DemoRelation']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('demo_types');
    }
};
```

File 'app/Demo/Database/Seeders/Seeder_DemoTypes.php':

```
namespace App\Demo\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class Seeder_DemoTypes extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('demo_types')) {
            DB::transaction(function () {
                DB::table('demo_types')->insert(['f_integer' => 1]);
                DB::table('demo_types')->insert(['f_integer' => 2]);
                DB::table('demo_types')->insert(['f_integer' => 3]);
            });
        }
    }
}
```